# Uninstall WP-CLI

Tags: wp-cli

I have WP CLI installed on my server. Is there a command to uninstall the package?

Here's where it's been installed on my server:

[image: Server Setup]

I'd rather uninstall the package vs using rm -r.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the `wp-cli.phar` file (and also the `.wp-cli` directory). I don't think there is an installation as such for you to un-install since typically you just download and move the wp-cli script to a directory such as `/usr/local/bin`.